# Using bcrypt on Node.js results in validation failed

Tags: node.js

I am writing code in Node.js to encrypt passwords using bcrypt.

However, if you use bcrypt, you will get an `ValidationError: User validation failed: password: Cast to String failed for value "Promise { <pending> }" at path "password"`

I do not get this error if I save it as plain text without encryption.

Is there a secret of bcrypt I do not know?

**bcrypt (not working)**

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

sign_up = (req, res, next) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  const User = User.findOne({ email: email });
  if (exUser) {
    return res.send('exist user');
  }
  const hash = bcrypt.hash(password, 8);
  const user = new User({
    email: email,
    password: hash
  });

  user.save((err) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    res.send('signup success');
  });
};
```

**no bcrypt (working)**

```
sign_up = (req, res, next) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  const User = User.findOne({ email: email });
  if (exUser) {
    return res.send('exist user');
  }
  const user = new User({
    email: email,
    password: password
  });

  user.save((err) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    res.send('signup success');
  });
};
```

Comment: `bcrypt.hash` is asynchronous, so you either need to use a callback or revert to the synchronous version, `bcrypt.hashSync`. Possibly helpful link: https://www.abeautifulsite.net/hashing-passwords-with-nodejs-and-bcrypt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on Chris's comment:

It appears that `bcrypt.hash` is asynchronous, and is returning a Promise.

To fix this, I would recommend using an async function and `await`ing the result. [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

This may require a newer version of NodeJS than what you are running.

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

// Async function allows us to use await
sign_up = async (req, res, next) => {

  const { email, password } = req.body;
  const User = User.findOne({ email: email });
  if (exUser) {
    return res.send('exist user');
  }

  // We await the result of the hash function
  const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, 8);

  const user = new User({
    email: email,
    password: hash
  });

  user.save((err) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    res.send('signup success');
  });
};
```

Do not use the `bcrypt.hashSync` function, as while it is running your server will not be able to do *anything* else.